# how to compare strings by using the shell command of raspbian

Tags: linux, string, shell, raspbian

I found the relative instructions for normal linux versions are not suitable for raspbian, on RaspberryPi.

For example, the following command won't work,

```
$s1='bigger'
$s2='smaller'

if (($s1==$s2)); then
  echo equal
else
  echo unequal
fi
```

Any ideas from experienced programmers? Thanks!

Comment: What is "normal linux"? What shell do you try to use? Your example won't work on any linux.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work for me either, on Debian. I'll answer assuming you're using `#!/bin/bash` (or similar constructs) as your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

I get the following error:

```
./b: line 2: =bigger: command not found
./b: line 3: =smaller: command not found
./b: line 5: ((: ==: syntax error: 
operand expected (error token is "==")
```

In general, `$` should not be used on the left side of assignments. Let's get rid of those.

```bash
s1='bigger'
s2='smaller'
```

This does run, but not as we desire.

Running the modified script will output `equal`. This is because your double parenthesis `((x == y))` are performing an [arithmetic equality](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) operation, which isn't what you want.

To check for string equality in bash, do:

```bash
if [[ $s1 == "$s2" ]]; then
```

Here I've quoted the right hand side of the condition to prevent [glob-matching](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

The [`[[` construct is distinct from `[`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and is both more powerful and slightly less portable.

The final script then looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s1='bigger'
s2='smaller'

if [[ $s1 == "$s2" ]]; then
  echo equal
else
  echo unequal
fi
```

This does what we expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this (after I just signed up!) because I was trying to do this, and this was the first question/answer I found.  I tried fermi-paradox's answer, but that did not work.  I got

> final.sh: 5: [[: not found

getting rid of the [[ and replacing with [ gave me

> final.sh: 5: [: bigger: unexpected operator

and searching again, I found another answer which led me to

```
#!/bin/bash
s1='bigger fish'
s2='smaller fish'

if [ "$s1" = "$s2" ]; then
  echo equal
else
  echo unequal
fi
```